# Is there identicon library for PHP

Tags: php, identicon

I'm looking for a PHP library/function/class which can create [Identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon)s.

Comment: what is the difference between identicons and gravatars?

Comment: A gravatar is a user selected image - identicons are generated based on an ip address or email address.  identicons / monsterids / visiglyphs are sometimes used as a fallback if no gravatar is available.

Comment: I haven't tested, but the 4th result when searching for "Identicon php": http://www.phpkode.com/scripts/item/php-identicons/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about [this](http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/wp_identicon/)

it's how Scott did the identicons for Wordpress, you can download the code and see for yourself.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

i use this:

```
class Gravatar
{
    static public function GetGravatarUrl( $email, $size = 128, $type = 'identicon', $rating = 'pg' )
    {
        $gravatar = sprintf( 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%s?d=%s&s=%d&r=%s',
                              md5( $email ), $type, $size, $rating );
        return $gravatar;
    }
}
```

Which is basically the same thing SO uses. It supports everything [gravatar.com](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement) supports.

Answer (score 2):

[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/identicons) has a PHP identicon implementation

Answer (score 1):

[PHPClasses](http://www.phpclasses.org/) didn't have anything - but you could have a look at this [MonsterID](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2007-01/20_monsterid_as_gravatar_fallback) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, I wondered why you asked, since you link to Wikipedia article which points to lot of implementations, including PHP ones. BTW, thanks for your question, I didn't know the name of these icons...

But after exploring a bit, I found lot of links there were outdated... Following the [Visiglyphs](http://digitalconsumption.com/forum/Visiglyphs-for-IP-visualisation) one, the original code is no longer available, but the author points to an alternative, OO version which can be downloaded. :-)

Note that author also wrote an interesting complement article: [How to create a Visiglyph cache](http://digitalconsumption.com/forum/Howto-create-a-Visiglyph-cache) .